# sum data from json with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

How can I display just the activity by "order" with external .json and js

external .json

```
[{
  "activity": "Shift Log",
  "lat": "53.3630",
  "lon": "-6.2432"
}, {
  "activity": "Shift Log",
  "lat": "53.3422",
  "lon": "-6.2617"
}, {
  "activity": "Clock In",
  "lat": "53.3431",
  "lon": "-6.2802"
}]
```

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
  <title>SUM ACTIVITY</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function sum (activity) {
        var min=1;
        var max = 4 // max number off json 
        var markersArray = [];
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*max)+min;
        var jsonfile = "pointer" + random.toString()+".json" //

        $.getJSON(jsonfile, function(pointer) {
            console.log("Loaded points from file: " + jsonfile);

                $.each(pointer, function(index, ponto) {
                console.log("Read points: " + JSON.stringify(ponto[0].length));

            });
        });
    }

    </script>
</html>
```

should be display number of activity's like 
Shift log = 2, Clock In = 1

Comment: The final sentence is not very clear to me...

Answer (score 0):

Just use Temp Array  to store the 'Shift log' and 'Clock In'

```
var shiftLogArr = [],
    clockInArray = [],
    shiflog = "Shift Log",
    clockin = "Clock In" ;

$.getJSON(jsonfile, function(pointer) {

  $.each(pointer, function(index, item) {
   if(item.activity === shiflog) {
    shiftLogArr.push(item);
   }

   if(item.activity === clockin) {
    clockInArray.push(item);
   } 

 });
});
```

It' just my opinion, hope this help!

Comment: some reason I'm not getting output. just add console.log, any idea?

Comment: I think you can use @David R's answer

Answer (score 0):

With UnderscoreJS, you can achieve this easily using the `_.countBy` function,

```
var jsonObj = [{
  "activity": "Shift Log",
  "lat": "53.3630",
  "lon": "-6.2432"
}, {
  "activity": "Shift Log",
  "lat": "53.3422",
  "lon": "-6.2617"
}, {
  "activity": "Clock In",
  "lat": "53.3431",
  "lon": "-6.2802"
}]

var countObjects = _.countBy(jsonObj, 'activity');

console.log(countObjects);
```

**Working JSFiddle** - https://jsfiddle.net/r7bfpdst/2/

Hope this helps!.